# PHP & SWF - Slide Show not Displaying

Tags: php, flash

I am trying to display a slideshow.
slide_auto.php is in **the same directory** as my **slideS_img** folder

Here is my slide_auto.php file:

```
<?php
$file_dir="slideS_img"; //change this to a folder name
$show_titles=false; //change to false if you don't want to see the captions
$omit_chars=0; //how many characters to cut off the title's front
$link_to_image=false; //do you want to display links?

print '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<slideshow  displayTime="5" 
            transitionSpeed=".7"
            ...more code...
            >';

            $dir=opendir($file_dir);
        $xml_string= array();
            while ($file=readdir($dir))
            {
                if(substr($file, -3) == "jpg" || substr($file, -4) == "jpeg" ){
                $tmp_str = '<image img="'.$file_dir.'/'.$file.'" ';
                if($show_titles){
                    $file_title=substr($file, $omit_chars, strpos($file, ".")-$omit_chars);
                    $tmp_str .= 'caption="'.$file_title.'" ';

                }

                if($link_to_image){
                    $link_title=substr($file, $omit_chars, strpos($file, ".")-$omit_chars);
                    $tmp_str .= 'link="'.$file_dir.'/'.$file.'" target="_blank"';

                }

                    $tmp_str .=" />";
                    array_push($xml_string, $tmp_str);
                }


            }
            sort($xml_string);
            for($i=0; $i<count($xml_string); $i++){
            print $xml_string[$i];
            }
closedir($dir);
print '</slideshow>';
?>
```

amd my slideshowpage.php:

```
<?php
require_once('slideshow/slide_auto.php')
?>

<!DOCTYPE>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<div align="center">
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div id="flashcontent">
  This text is replaced by the Flash movie.
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   swfobject.embedSWF("slideshow.swf?file=slideshow/slide_auto.php", "gallery", "100%", "100%", "7", "#333333");
   so.write("flashcontent");
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get an error saying **Warning: opendir(slideS_img) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /[path]/slideshow/slide_auto.php on line 62**

Any help?
Thank you

Comment: try $file_dir = './';, you said they are in the same folder

Comment: @Alexios but how will it recognize that is the slideS_img directory that has to be opened? Ευχαριστώ ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marc is actually right in his solution. If I could try to elaborate a bit, when you include slide_auto.php, you can think the following happening:

1. PHP inserts the text from the file slide_auto.php, where the include command is found.
2. So, when $file_dir="slideS_img"; comes up it tries to find the directory under slideshowpage.php, **not slide_auto.php**.

This fails because the actual image folder is in directory **slideshow**.

If you call slide_auto.php directly (or within the Flash application), then its directory is slideshow, and you should be able to get the XML without any further errors.

Comment: I just changed my "slideS_img" with the complete path e.g. home/main/slideshow/slideS_img and id did found it I thing but my new error is "swfobject is not defined" Do I miss anything? Thank you

Comment: Now you're not including whatever .js file you've got the swfobject class defined in.

Answer (score 1):

included files assume the working directory of the file you've included them from. Your parent slideshowpage script is in (say)

```
 /home/sites/example.com/html
```

which will become the working directory of your slideshow script. So the opendir is actually being done as

```
 /home/sites/example.com/html/slideS_img
```

instead of

```
 /home/sites/example.com/html/slideshow/slideS_image
```

You'll have to modify your opendir call to use a more specific directory.

Comment: my slideshowpage.php is out of my slideshow folder which contains slide_auto.php and slideS_img folder. I don't see where I am wrong.

Comment: no, your include() shows that slide_auto.php is in a subdirectory of whatever directory that slideshowpage.php is in.

Comment: I am confused... slideshowpage.php is under [maindir]. slideS_img folder and slide_auto.php are under[main/slideshow]

Comment: Yes, and when you load slide_auto.php into slideshowpage.php with include(), its default working directory is that of slideshowpage.php. so when you say opendir(slideS_img), it'll try to opened in the same dir as slidesehowpage.ph

Comment: I added a comment on above post